# I can't make instance using TensorFlow on Android-Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tensorflow

I want to use TensorFlow graph on Android-Studio.
To begin with, I could import org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface. But I couldn't make instance.
Here is MainActivity.java.

```
package com.example.maguro.mnist_beginner;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static{
        System.loadLibrary("tensorflow_inference");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface();

    }
}
```

Error point is last discription.

```
TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface();
```

Error said "Cannot resolve constructor "TensorFlowInferenceInterface();".
Although I refered to 2 homepages, I received this error.
http://docs.fabo.io/tensorflow/android/run.html
https://qiita.com/ohisama@github/items/f2fdd384a5e305462a79

And I edit 2 files."settings.gradle" & "app/build.gradle"
Here is settings.gradle.

```
include ':app',':TensorFlow-Android-Inference'
findProject(":TensorFlow-Android-Inference").projectDir = new File("/home/maguro/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/android/cmake")
```

And here is app/build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.maguro.mnist_beginner"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets{
        main{
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    debugCompile project(path:':TensorFlow-Android-Inference',configuration:'debug')
    releaseCompile project(path:':TensorFlow-Android-Inference',configuration:'release')
}
```

------My environment------
OS:Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Tensorflow:Used Anaconda for GPU for python3.6
Android-Studio:2.3.3
CUDA toolkit:8.0
cuDNN:6.0

I can't use English well.
If I have said something rude, I'm sorry.
Please lend me a hand.

Comment: do you have libtensorflow_inference.so in your project?

Comment: Yes, I made directories that have app/src/main/assets/libtensorflow_inference.so.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the prior comment. I made directories that have app/libs/libandroid_tensorflow_inference.java.jar and app/libs/arm64-v8a/libtensorflow_inference.so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, there is no constructor for `TensorFlowInferenceInterface` that takes no arguments.

From [the source file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java), I see three constructors:

- `TensorFlowInferenceInterface(AssetManager assetManager, String model)`
- `TensorFlowInferenceInterface(InputStream is)`
- `TensorFlowInferenceInterface(Graph g)`

So, you'd have to use one of those.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you!! But now, I don't have experiment PC. Tomorrow, I will try it.

Comment: After I add 3 constructors, Android-Studio didn't tell me error! Thank you for teaching me!! :)

Comment: Excuse me. After I resolved question, what do I act?(e.g. clicking checkmark, evaluating you). Sorry, please tell me.